# Can address change when passing a c++ vector by pointer

Tags: c++, std

If I have something like the code below, where I pass a vector pointer (e.g. it can be null), then in the called function I add items to the vector, is there danger that my vector pointer can become invalid? The same goes for passing by reference. Since vector is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory and will reallocate as needed is there danger that I could get a dangling pointer because the vector is relocated in memory? The code below is trivial but what if myVecFunc was adding a million values, or some large objects? I've seen library code that follows this pattern but it seems like you could run into trouble by doing this?
EDIT: Edited code to do *mVec->push_back(someNumber)

```
void myVecFunc(std::vector<double>* myVec)
{
     if (myVec != nullptr)
     {
        myVec->push_back(someNumber);
     }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<double> myVec;
   myVecFunc(&myVec);
}
```

Comment: Definitely use a reference, not a pointer. And yes, it is **safe** to do so. It is actually common for a function with a `std::vector<...>&` parameter to call `reserve()` first thing in its body so that memory is reallocated to what it is going to need (it makes the function faster by guaranteeing only 1 reallocation occurs, that it occurs before new elements are inserted + it guarantees you can use iterators without risk, since it will not reallocate).

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: `myVec` itself cannot and will not be realloacted by a call to a member function. it has its own internal pointer for managing the dynamically allocated array (which can refer to different addresses after a `push_back`)

Comment: Just write `void myVecFunc(std::vector<double>& myVec)  {   myVec.push_back(someNumber); }` And you will not even have to do nullptr validation.

Comment: It's common to have optional parameters that are pointers so that they can be `nullptr`.  Hence, OP's original question of the difference between the address of the object changing vs. the internal address of the object buffer changing on a realloc (for example) is a good one - has nothing to do with changing it to a reference.  @UnholySheep got it right.  Changing the signature to a reference is not the right answer in this situation.  It would be if the precondition of the parameter was that it be non-`nullptr`, but that's not the question.

Comment: @franji1 please do not alter the question to fix code when there are answers already. When you do, you should at least inform the answers so they can be fixed. In the current state my answer starts with nonsense. Nerermind, I noticed by chance, and will fix, but usually broken code is for the questions and fixes is for the answers

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Sorry - when I placed my comment - there wasn't an answer, but then I immediately edited the question (oops).  I did get to see your answer addressing the same issue of my fix - then saw you modified your answer (again, sorry).  My intent (based on my comment) was that people were commenting thinking the signature needed to be a reference because the client code did NOT pass `&myVec` but (I presume) a reference-looking parameter, hence the misleading comments about references.  Your answer nails it.

Comment: Your edit is wrong. Either do `(*myVec).push_back(...)` (note the extra parenthesis around `*myVec`) or `myVec->push_back(...)`(No asterisk here). The latter form is almost always preferred. Or in your case, just pass by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, you have two fundamental misunderstandings.

First, passing a pointer to a function: Function arguments are passed by value (unless you use references), pointers are no exception:

```
 void foo(int*);

 // usage
 int* x = nullptr;
 foo(x);
 assert( x == nullptr);
```

There is no way the assert could fail, because `foo` cannot modify `x`. In your example `myVecFunc` cannot modify the addressof `myVec`. The memory location of an object is tied to its identity. During lifetime it doesnt change. If you copy a vector to a different location, you get a copy.

---

Next `std::vector`. A vector internally stores a pointer to dynamically allocated memory used for the elements. The memory is properly managed by the vector. For example, you can copy a vector and it will copy the elements. You can pass a vector by pointer or by reference, no problem at all.

What can happen on a reallcoation that the pointer that the vector stores internally gets a different value. Hence this code should not be written like this:

```
std::vector<int> foo(2); // vector of size 2
int* ptr = foo.data();   // pointer to the internal array
foo.push_back(42);       // iterators and pointers are invalidated
std::cout << *ptr;       // DO NOT DERFERENCE THE INVALID POINTER !
```

---

In summary: There is nothing wrong in the code you show. However, you should only pass arguments by pointer when `nullptr` is a valid input. Otherwise use a reference.

Comment: _There is nothing wrong in the code you show._ Except, that is, `*myVec.push_back(someNumber);` should be `myVec->push_back(someNumber);`.

Comment: agreed myVec->push_back(...) is equivalent to (*myVec).push_back(...)